# Signup/login works on Localhost but not on Heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku

===============UPDATE======================

## I needed to add the token secret to the config vars on Heroku.

My web-app works on localhost, but after deploying to Heroku singup/login doesn't work (don't know about other features, which require login). I'm connected to the mlab properly (when I post on localhost I see data on Heroku URL as well).

I have attached Heroku logs below. On the my Chrome console I get 503 (Service Unavailable). [my Heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdHRh.png)

P.S. Just graduated from a coding bootcamp, sorry if my terminology isn't accurate.

Thanks,
Arik

Here is the jwt code:

```js
 * Login required middleware
 */
exports.ensureAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({ msg: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
};
  /**
   * POST /login
   * Sign in with email and password
   */
  exports.loginPost = function(req, res, next) {
    req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.assert('email', 'Email cannot be blank').notEmpty();
    req.assert('password', 'Password cannot be blank').notEmpty();
    req.sanitize('email').normalizeEmail({ remove_dots: false });

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
      return res.status(400).send(errors);
    }

    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).send({ msg: 'The email address ' + req.body.email + ' is not associated with any account. ' +
        'Double-check your email address and try again.'
        });
      }
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (!isMatch) {
          return res.status(401).send({ msg: 'Invalid email or password' });
        }
        res.send({ token: generateToken(user), user: user.toJSON() });
      });
    });
  };

/**
 * POST /signup
 */
exports.signupPost = function(req, res, next) {
  req.assert('name', 'Name cannot be blank').notEmpty();
  req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.assert('email', 'Email cannot be blank').notEmpty();
  req.assert('password', 'Password must be at least 4 characters long').len(4);
  req.sanitize('email').normalizeEmail({ remove_dots: false });

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    return res.status(400).send(errors);
  }

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
    if (user) {
    return res.status(400).send({ msg: 'The email address you have entered is already associated with another account.' });
    }
    user = new User({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    });
    user.save(function(err) {
    res.send({ token: generateToken(user), user: user });
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The logs throws this error: ErrorType: secret must be a string or buffer. Can you provide some code, exactly when you interact with jsonwebtoken and when you set the secret token?

Maybe in localhost on a development environment you are attaching the secret correctly but in production this variable are not defined correctly.

Otherwise you are getting 503 because the server crashed.

Comment: Thanks Mateo, really appreciate your help. I added the code, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Solved, I needed to add the token secret to the config vars on Heroku. Thanks Mateo